# Outer join for Alias name and column name -Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I had a working sample query earlier in my code as mentioned below.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       nombre_aplicacion,
       APLICACION,
       NOMBRE_APLCODE,
       DESCRIPCION,
       AREAFUNC
FROM   (
  select **CODAPLICATION nombre_aplicacion**,
         APLICACION,
         NOMBRE_APLCODE,
         DESCRPTION,
         AREAFUNC
  from   admin.VW_APLICACIONES@dblink,
         admin.VW_PRODUCTOS@dblink
  where  **nombre_aplicacion (+) = CODAPLICATION**
)
WHERE  1=1
ORDER BY nombre_aplicacion ASC;
```

When I try similar type of query with different tables I was getting error as invalid ORA-00904: "NOMBRE_APLICACION": invalid identifier.

If I remove **nombre_aplicacion (+) = CODAPLICATION** in where condition query is fetching the result. Can any one suggest why I was facing error as its working earlier with sample query and I was getting error? Is this join is valid?

Comment: Your query would be clearer if you prefixed all the column names with the table (or an alias for it) that they each belong to. Modern join syntax would probably help too. It appears that one of APLICACIONES and PRODUCTOS has a column called NOMBRE_APLICACION while the other has a column called CODAPLICATION - which you are, a bit confusingly, aliasing as NOMBRE_APLICACION. Including your table definitions in the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The query is not valid as:

- In the inner sub-query you select `areafunc` and in the outer query you use `area` which does not appear in the inner sub-query so will not be available.
- In the inner sub-query, you define `CODAPLICATION` to have the alias `nombre_aplicacion` and then you try to use that alias in the `WHERE` clause as a join condition; that will not work.

You have not described which column belongs to which table but you want something like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       a.codaplication AS nombre_aplicacion,
       a.aplicacion, 
       a.nombre_aplcode,
       p.descrption,
       p.areafunc
from   APLICACIONES a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTOS p
       ON (a.primary_key_column = p.foreign_key_column)
ORDER BY nombre_aplicacion ASC;
```

*Note: you are going to have to correct the code to give the correct table aliases for each column and give the correct columns for the join condition.*

Comment: What if we dont know/have primary and foreign key between tables ? I have edited my sample query, that is working query previously.. the DB has been deleted so we need to change the tables/modify query, when I was trying similar query with new tables I was unable to do outer join on alias column . My drought is who it got worked on query :select CODAPLICATION nombre_aplicacion,
         APLICACION,
         NOMBRE_APLCODE,
         DESCRPTION,
         AREAFUNC
  from   admin.VW_APLICACIONES@dblink,
         admin.VW_PRODUCTOS@dblink
  where  nombre_aplicacion (+) = CODAPLICATION

Comment: @Sweety23 You need to join the tables on columns from each table that contain the same information. Typically this means that there is a foreign-key constraint on one table that points to a primary key (or unique) constraint on the other table but it could be some other relationship. We can't tell you want the join condition should be as they are your tables and you should know what the columns in each table represent and which ones would be the identifiers you want to join on.